# OL3 Color Icon in KML

Tags: openlayers-3

Now I am trying to migrate  Google Earth to OpenLayers 3 (version 3.11.1)

I use a KML file, while viewing with GE, the icon is colored but with OL3, the color is not displayed

Here is my code snippet to post this KML file:

```
 var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');

    var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
            imagerySet: 'Aerial',
            key: 'Ak-dzM4wZjSqTlzveKz5u0d4IQ4bRzVI309GxmkgSVr1ewS6iPSrOvOKhA-CJlm3'
        })
    });

    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: '/UsersFiles/KMLTest.kml',
            format: new ol.format.KML({ extractStyles: true })
        })
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: document.getElementById('map4'),
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [0 ,0],
            projection: projection,
            zoom: 0
        })
    });
```

the result is on the image below:

[Icon in Google Earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAUd6.jpg)

[Icon in OL3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU5q4.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried without extracting styles: format: `new ol.format.KML()`?

Comment: But if you want to style in OL take a look at this example - http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/examples/kml-earthquakes.html

Comment: have you solved this? I am on version 3.19 and I have the same problem when loading a simple kml with markers with background color?

Comment: I have not found the solution yet. I just have to color all used icons with predefined color in photoshop